# Why would you want to set system properties such as java.vm.specification.version on App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, system-properties

According to the App Engine documentation, you can set system properties and environment variables for your app in the deployment descriptor and App Engine sets the following system properties when it initializes the JVM on an app server:

```
* file.separator
* path.separator
* line.separator
* java.version
* java.vendor
* java.vendor.url
* java.class.version
* java.specification.version
* java.specification.vendor
* java.specification.name
* java.vm.vendor
* java.vm.name
* java.vm.specification.version
* java.vm.specification.vendor
* java.vm.specification.name
* user.dir
```

Why would you want to set any of these system properties?

Comment: Are you sure you can really set any of the above? In any case, the ability to set system properties is more about setting application-specific properties (think oauth.consumerkey) that your code or some library would like to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be used as a workaround to make existing libraries work which may depend on particular values for these properties.

Comment: Agreed ... but you probably shouldn't if you don't have to.